# Is it possible to send query to online database from an electron application?

Tags: mysql, ajax, database, desktop-application, electron

I've been looking at solutions so that I can create a cross-platform fluid experience. So to do this for the online website version, I would just send an Ajax request to a PHP script to query a MySQL database. But I am thinking of creating an electron app for offline use, so I will need to send queries to that online database, but I know there are a lot of limitations when it comes to Ajax with regards to cross-site requests.

So is it possible to send these sort of ajax requests to a PHP script on a web server, from an electron application. But, if Ajax requests aren't possible, how would I achieve this type of request to an online database. I have tried doing some research on the subject but was unable to find any solutions that are similar to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-domain AJAX requests are blocked *by default*. All your regular desktop apps such as your Mail client send requests out all the time. You simply have to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on your server. I don't know what server application you're using (Apache/Nginx), but for Apache you can start simply by adding the following line to the relevant part of your Virtual Host or .htaccess file:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

You can refer to the [Enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) to learn how to enable CORS for other server technologies.

Comment: Sweet, yes my server runs Apache so that's an easy addition, though are there any security problems with allowing all requests? Also, do directories without htaccess files use rules from its parent directory/'s?

Comment: No security problems, CORS is pretty much how API calls from the browser to other services work. Think Google's Firebase for one. The only security problems will be on the end of your app, so you have to implement proper access control as you would in any app of yours whether it has CORS or not.

RE your question on .htaccess, there's a good discussion on that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443902/get-htaccess-from-root-directory-to-apply-on-all-directories